# background position increment effect when load

Tags: javascript, css

I want to create effect on my page. I have a cloud image. When page load cloud image in background should move.

```
<img src="bg.jpg" alt="bg">
```

How to create this effect using JavaScript backgroundPosition?

Comment: what you have tried so far ??

Comment: i am creating a page. in background i wanna that cloud should move. i need javascript code for moving clouds picture using javascript

Comment: (instead of pure js) Refer to this jQuery plugin [jqlouds](http://enricodeleo.github.io/jqlouds/)

Comment: can you explain it plz

Comment: refer to my answer :) i hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to include references for [*jQlouds*](http://enricodeleo.github.io/jqlouds/) plugin:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqlouds/0.2.3/jquery.jqlouds.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqlouds/0.2.3/jquery.jqlouds.min.js"></script>
```

Then you can select an element you want make it as a SKY, *For example:*

***HTML:***

```
<div id="sky" style="height:400px; background-color: blue;">

</div>
```

***JS :***

```
$('#sky').jQlouds({
  minClouds: 8, // minimum amount of clouds
  maxClouds: 10, // maximum amount of clouds
  wind: true,
});
```

You can refer to plugin [*Documentation*](https://github.com/enricodeleo/jqlouds) for more options.

See [**JsFiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Shady_Alset/pe9888hx/), *I hope it works for you, Thanks*

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Javascript, you can actually do it with CSS3 only, here's an example, you can change the parameters if you want :

```css
@keyframes bgPosition {
  from {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
  }

  to {
    background-position: 65px 0px;
  }
}

body {
  background-image : url('http://images.clipartpanda.com/white-clouds-png-white-cloud-clipart-png-179.jpg');
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: 65px 60px;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-name: bgPosition;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```